# Javascript innerhtml of checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Well I have some checkboxes with id='0','1','2','3' etc. So I need to get text of checkboxes. Here is code of checkboxes in PHP.

```
'<input id="'.$i.'"type="checkbox" name="option1" value="a1" onclick="checkYears()">'.$years[$i].'</input>
```

So i need to get $years[$i]-value.
I'm using this code.

```
while (bool==false)
    {
        if (document.getElementById(i)!=null)
        {
            if (document.getElementById(i).checked)
            {
                years.push(1);
                yearsValue.push(document.getElementById(i).innerHTML);
                document.getElementById(i).innerText="WORKS";
                console.log(yearsValue[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                years.push(0);
                yearsValue.push(document.getElementById(i)).innerHTML);
                console.log(yearsValue[i]);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            bool=true;
        }
        i++;
    }
```

0's and 1's are added ok, but when i'm trying to use innerHTML there is and undefined values in consle.

Any suggestions?

Comment: thank you, for you answers they were helpfull.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

InnerHTML gets the HTML *content* of an element. i.e. the data between the start tag and the end tag. Inputs are empty elements, they cannot have content (in HTML (as opposed to XHTML) they cannot have an end tag either). Your HTML is invalid and you should use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org).

You probably want something like this:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Text label</span>
</label>
```

Then you could get:

```
checkbox.parentNode.innerHTML;
```

or

```
checkbox.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

An input element does not have an innerhtml because the element is supposed to be self-closing:

`<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can't because `<input>` doesn't have close tag, so it doesn't have `innerHTML` property:

> Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Input).

I recomend you to use combination of [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/Label) and input.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally a input element will not have any innerHTML. That means you cannot have an enclosing html content in input element. You can just have value of input element.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, input elements are self-closing and do not have innerHTML. Best solution if you want to catch the plain text next to the checkbox element would be to use "nextElementSibling" and "innerText".

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> <span>Text to get...</span>
<button onclick="getText()">Get Text</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function getText() {
     console.log(document.getElementById("checkbox1").nextElementSibling.innerText);
}
```