# Dynamically Created Checkbox calculation, Not showing properly

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have a javascript function that create Checkbox by drop_down's selection. When I clicked the add button , system will create checkbox(es) with values.

```
function addElement() 
    {

      var e= document.getElementById('top-addon');
      var tops = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
      var tops_value=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

     // alert(tops_value);

      var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');

      num += 1;
      //var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

      var countedName = num;

     // newdiv.setAttribute('id',Name);

        var x = document.createElement("input");
        x.type = "checkbox";
        x.name = "toppings[]";
        x.setAttribute('id',countedName);
        x.checked = true;
        x.value = tops_value;   
        //var inner_text = tops + '<a href=\'#\' onclick=\'removeElement('+countedName+')\'> [x] </a>';
        //var text= document.createTextNode(inner_text);
        x.innerHTML=tops;

        ni.appendChild(x);
        //ni.appendChild(inner_text);
    }
```

I had make some screenshots to explain you my current problems. Please check my screenshot for more clear picture.

[image]

This is like this, for an item like ice-cream, customers can add many toppings example , nuts, jelly etc.

Then  I have another problem.Created checkbox's are not shown . I can only see square box(es)

Please see my second attached picture below.Seems okay to me.But I can't see any description text(s).
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is

1. to show selection
2. Calculate the items,they will be generated with checked value. I have already achieve the code to remove the generated toppings. So I want to calculate the total value of generated items  and they should be changeable.

Example. if remove a generated item. Total toppings should decrease.Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: all I need to achieve is simple, when a toppings is add update total . When a topping is remove update total.

Comment: Need to create associated label elements with checkbox if you want to display text with checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem: In order to display text for a checkbox, you should put checkbox inside label. Here is modified code for you

```
function addElement() 
{

    var e= document.getElementById('top-addon');
    var tops = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var tops_value=e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    // alert(tops_value);

    var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    num += 1;
    //var newdiv = document.createElement('div');

    var countedName = num;

    // newdiv.setAttribute('id',Name);

    var x = document.createElement("input");
    x.type = "checkbox";
    x.name = "toppings[]";
    x.setAttribute('id',countedName);
    x.checked = true;
    x.value = tops_value;   
    //x.innerHTML=tops; We don't need to set text to checkbox.

    /* These lines are added */
    var label = document.createElement("label");


    label.appendChild(x);

    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.innerText = tops;

    label.appendChild(span);

    /* End of added lines */

    // Beware that we are adding label to div, instead of checkbox.
    ni.appendChild(label);
}
```

For your second problem: To calculate grand total of cart, you need to define a function (let's say calculateTotal) that implements sort of this pseudocode:

```
function calculateTotal
begin
        get all checkboxes under myDiv
        for each selected check box
        begin
                get check box id
                get substring of id, after comma (",")
                add substring (price) to total
        end
end
```

This method should be triggered whenever user clicks add item button, remove item button, and checkboxs' onChange events fire.

Comment: let me try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I got it working for dynmaic adding and deleting but still stack at checkbox calculation step. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess this answer should address your issue with checkboxes text: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143276/1492792